# Arcore preview 2 apk doesn't work on note8

Tags: arcore

I bought note 8 in order to use arcore development services.(there is notice that galaxy note8 is available for using arcore services)
But when I play program i made with arcore the app stops and turns off.

Comment: That is quite unanswerable. Welcome to SO but please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is out of preview, since has just released version 1. Enjoy.